# Change Number Style

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, cross-reference

I can add a dynamic page number reference to a particular bookmark by doing the following:

Insert → Cross-Reference

- Type → Bookmarks
- Insert Reference To → Page

My question is: How do I have the page number to have leading zeros, if necessary?

Eg.

```
  1 → 001
 10 → 010
999 → 999
```

Normally, I would right-click on the number, select "Numbers" then change the format, but it does not appear for cross-references.

Comment: There may be no way within LibreOffice itself, but if you use an extension for PDF output, it will reformat with leading zeros: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=69510

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=69510), the only way is to add zeroes before the field.  The following is a complex but automatic solution to do this.

As an example, enter "Bookmarked text" on page 15 of a document.  On the same line, insert a page number field by going to `Insert -> Page Number`.

Before the page number, we need to insert two fields, one for each of the possible zeroes.  To do this, go to `Insert -> Fields -> More Fields` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.  Under the Functions tab, with Type `Conditional text`, enter the "Condition" as `Page < 100`.  Enter 0 for "Then" and leave "Else" empty.  Now press Insert.

[image: insert field]

Now modify the condition to `Page < 10` and press Insert again, to create the other possible zero.  Then press Close.

Next, select the page number and the leading zeros fields.  Go to `Insert -> Bookmark` and give it a name.  Also, go to `Format -> Character` and under Font Effects, change the font color to white so that it doesn't show up when printed.  (Changing the text to hidden will cause the page number not to be updated, so don't do that).

[image: page 15]

Finally, go to a different page and do `Insert -> Cross-reference` to the bookmark we just created.  The Type is `Bookmarks` and Insert reference to `Reference`.

[image: page 17]

For other bookmarks, the three fields (page number plus two conditional zeroes) can be copied and pasted.

Conditional text is explained [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Conditions#To_display_conditional_text_based_on_the_number_of_pages:).